# Solana Program 1 time initialization Issue

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-lang, cargo, rustc

I want to add a check that once a function is called it should never be called again. I want initialization to be one-time only. Is this a good approach if I take a bool value and set it to false after initialization and check if it's false then don't run the function? Or is there a standard or better way?

P.S = In short I want a smart contract once initialized should never be able to initialize again.

Answer (score 3):

in short you can create a PDA with a pre-defined seed to store a state when you init. if you are gonna call init again, it will error out because you already created a PDA, which will fail the init check. In anchor, this is done by using account macro 'init' for instance:

```
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [
            b"sample".as_ref(),
        ],
        payer=payer,
        space=Sample::LEN,
        bump,
    )]
    pub sample: Account<'info, Sample>
```

if you are try to call this instruction again, anchor will check if the provided account is initialized already. Since your instruction uses the same seed, it will not pass the init check thus this instruction will not be executed.

Comment: well, I am using ```init_if_needed``` instead of ```init``` as I have a scenario where I want to initialize on run time (not right after deployment on mainnet) if it's not initialized. But ```init_if_needed``` updates the variables as well. So I guess bool check is the best. Thanks for help.